# the pronunciation of "get"

Tags: pronunciation

Both /gɛt/ and /gɪt/ show up in the Wiktionary. The etymology strongly suggests that the pronunciation /gɛt/ is older.  What is the source of the pronunciation /gɪt/?  Is it confined to certain regions?

It does not seem to be coming from a regular sound change, as nobody says /pɪt/ for /pet/. On the other hand, it does affect "forget" (at least for me).

Comment: _Pet_ is not an auxiliary verb, and is not regularly reduced in speech. By far the most common pronunciation of _get_ is [ɡɨt], with a high central lax vowel [ɨ], as in [ɡɨ'ɾaɾɨhɪr/ 'Get out of here'. With less centralization, high front lax /ɪ/ is common for a reduced mid front lax /ɛ/.

Comment: Assuming OP isn't from Australia, South Africa, or some other place where /ɛ/ is routinely enunciated as /ɪ/, I think he's atypical if he does this with *forget*. For most native speakers, *"Git!"* (as in *"Get going!, Giddyup!"* is really just an idiomatic affectation. It doesn't affect pronunciation of the vowel in *other* contexts.

Comment: Certainly a lot of speakers pronounce "git" for "get" in all contexts -- it's listed in several dictionaries, for instance. I was quite surprised to learn that there were speakers who didn't. (I am from the US and would describe my accent as Standard American.) I have not found the "forget" pronunciation in a dictionary, though.

Comment: @hunter - I've seen folks come on here and use that same "Standard American" phrase, then throw out some crazy phrase or pronunciation unique to one small area. If you are going to discuss USA accents, it may be best to do some research to figure out exactly what regional accent you have (eg: Mine is Southern Midlands, which sounds like "no accent" to a lot of Americans, but does have some quirks)

Comment: @hunter: I don't "git" that. Are you saying it was a surprise to you to learn that *most* native speakers don't consistently say either *git* or *get?* That you've never heard/seen written anything like [*“They was just to **get** yer attention.” ... “Yer kind don' belong here no more. “Now, **git** goin', ya hear me?”*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22get+yer+attention%22+%22now+git%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1) I think that's not uncommon.

Comment: @FumbleFingers No, I mean I was surprised when I learned a few years ago that anyone ever pronounced the word "get" the way it was spelled; I thought it was just an irregularly spelled word that everyone pronounced "git" in all contexts.

Comment: @hunter: Now I really *am* intrigued. Even if every single native speaker in your area always says "git" (which does seem rather unlikely to me), surely you must have heard the "standard" pronunciation practically every time you heard someone from a different area (on TV, radio, etc.).

Comment: @fumblefingers once someone pointed out to me that lots of people say "get" it was indeed instantly obvious that that was what people on TV, radio, etc. were usually saying (as well as many of my friends). Maybe it was the same way with you when you first learned that lots of people say "berry/Barry" or "cot/caught" differently (or the same, depending on which one you grew up doing...)?

Comment: @hunter: Well, the reason ***I*** upvoted the question is because I really do think it's interesting that quite a lot of people say the single word *"Git!"* when they mean *"Get going! Get a move on!"*, even though they might rarely (if ever) use that form in any other context. I don't think it's really the same thing as your "berry/Barry, cot/caught" examples, where certain vowel shifts are *consistently* applied by speakers of the relevant dialect.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The pronunciation of "get" is indeed a very regional thing. I believe the "prestige" pronunciation in the USA is "/gɛt/". However [Southern American English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Southern_American_English) shifts a lot of vowels up, including shifting "get" to /gɪt/. The related [African-American Vernacular English](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/African_American_Vernacular_English) has the same feature. That means the predominant accents in both the Southeast quarter of USA and in most of its larger urban areas uses /gɪt/.

It's even a bit more complicated than that though. My own accent (I believe a mixture of Midlands and [Southern Midlands](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midland_American_English#South_Midland)) pronounces the word slightly differently depending on where it appears in the phrase. If it's in the middle, it is more likely to be closer to "/gɛt/", while at the end, it's more like "/gɪt/".

For instance, when my kids were in daycare, a popular mantra from the daycare workers was:

"You get what you get, and you don't throw a fit."

The way this is pronounced, the two phrases rhyme. However, the two "get"s don't quite rhyme with each other.

Comment: My daughters learned the mantra: *"you get what you get, and you don't get upset."*

Comment: @PeterShor - Interesting. Perhaps here it was changed to rhyme better with our accent (or visa-versa, depending on where it was coined).

Comment: Well ... enough of the country says *'git'* that I wouldn't venture to guess which mantra came first.

Comment: Actually, my money would be on somewhere that uses "/gɪt/", as "throw a fit" seems like it would be a much more familiar concept to a pre-schooler than "get upset".

Answer (score -1):

Upper class English pronunciation: git rhymes with bit. This the southern pronunciation of git!

Comment: Questions should be answered as an expert would answer them: comprehensively, with explanation and context. Explain why your answer is right, ideally with citations. Unsupported answers may be removed.